# How to render custom fonts in the <select> tag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, fonts

I have a set of the custom fonts (not the system fonts) that I want to use in one of my page (MVC 3). I want to display that fonts in a `<select>` tag but is it possible to render the text inside each element as its font style ?

In other words, I want to render e.g that font [image]

in one of the select's tag items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes You declare it in the CSS like this:

```
 @font-face { font-family: urfont; src: url('urfont.otf'); } 
 @font-face { font-family: urfont; font-weight: bold; src: url('urfont.otf');}
```

Then, you can just reference it like the other standard fonts:

```
<select style="font-family: urfont, sans-serif;"
```

Comment: This works, except for in Chrome and Safari.  Here's a [good article](http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/) on the topic.